# Generic Pattern: Cannot deserialize the JSON array

Tags: c#, arrays, json, generics, serialization

I am trying to write a generic pattern to deserialize my json array string.
i have the following object created bellow:

```
public interface IDataResponse<T> where T: class
{
    List<T> Data { get; set; }
}

public class DataResponse<T>: IDataResponse<T> where T: class
{
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public List<T> Data { get; set; }
}
```

My json format

```
{  
   "values":{  
   "value":[  
     {  
        "value_1":"aaaaaa",
        "value_2":"aaaaaa",
        "value_3":"aaaaaa"
     },
     {  
        "value_1":"bbbbbb",
        "value_2":"bbbbbb",
        "value_3":"bbbbbb"
     }
  ]
  }
}
```

Now i can use this pattern like that

```
var myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DataResponse<MyData>>>(result);
```

where **result** is the json array string.

But ruuning this code , i got the exception bellow

> Cannot deserialize the JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type ' ' because type requires JSON object (e.g. {“name”:“value”}) to deserialize correctly

How cani fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure to well understand but, Haven't you missed the parent container of your list ?

I share you a code to desrialize your data

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string result = @"
{  
   'values':{  
   'value':[
     {  
        'value_1':'aaaaaa',
        'value_2':'aaaaaa',
        'value_3':'aaaaaa'
     },
     {  
        'value_1':'bbbbbb',
        'value_2':'bbbbbb',
        'value_3':'bbbbbb'
     }
  ]
  }
}";

            var myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyContent<MyData>>(result);
        }
    }

    public class MyContent<T> where T : class
    {

        [JsonProperty("values")]
        public DataResponse<T> Values { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class MyData
    {
        public string value_1 { get; set; }
        public string value_2 { get; set; }
        public string value_3 { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IDataResponse<T> where T : class
    {
        List<T> Data { get; set; }
    }

    public class DataResponse<T> : IDataResponse<T> where T : class
    {
        [JsonProperty("value")]
        public List<T> Data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that there is no matching class for the `values` part of your `json` data. You need to change the structure of your `json` or you'll have to add another (root) class:

```
public class DataRoot<T> where T : class
{
    public DataResponse<T> Values { get; set;}
}

public interface IDataResponse<T> where T : class
{
    List<T> Data { get; set; }
}

public class DataResponse<T> : IDataResponse<T> where T : class
{
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public List<T> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can get your data like this:

```
var myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataRoot<MyData>>(result).Values;
```